# Sum of input fields can't be more than account balance

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying have users add dollar amounts to certain products that contain input fields for each product. The tricky part is the total of all fields can not exceed their account balance.

I can't seem to figure out how to detect if all input fields are more than the balance and then set the input field that has more than the balance to the remaining balance. Or, if there the remaining balance is already zero then the number entered into the input field would switch to zero/no actions would take place.

I've created a JSFiddle here. https://jsfiddle.net/12agemfe/1/

```js
var qty = $('input[type=text]');
var accountbalance = parseInt($('#accountbalance').text());
var removebalance;
var newbalance;

$('input').on('focusout', function() {
  //set removebalance to zero each time
  removebalance = 0;
  //get total from all input fields
  $(qty).each(function() {
    removebalance += parseFloat($(this).val());
  });
  //set current balance
  newbalance = (parseFloat(accountbalance).toFixed(2) 
                - parseFloat(removebalance).toFixed(2));
  //Needs to set input to zero and not update #accountbalance
  //if entering more than #account balance
  //Needs to correct input value if entered more than remaining balance
  if (newbalance < 0) {
    alert('You Can Not Cash out more than your Balance!');
    return false;
  }
  //once input fields are totaled, update the balance on the screen
  //should not allow negative balance and needs two decimal points
  //  parseFloat.fixedTo(2)
  $('#accountbalance').text(newbalance);
});

//Cant submit if input is more than balance
$('input[type=submit]').click(function() {
  if (newbalance < 0) {
    alert('You Can Not Cash out more than your Balance!');
    return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" name="value[]" value="0.00">
  <input type="text" name="value[]" value="0.00">
  <input type="text" name="value[]" value="0.00">
  <input type="text" name="value[]" value="0.00">
  <input type="text" name="value[]" value="0.00">
</form>

<div id="accountbalance">500</div>
<button id="submit">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have slightly changed script in fork from Your jsfiddle. Here it is - 
https://jsfiddle.net/xqhnyf0k/2/

Most important changes are in consequences of **newbalance** lower than 0. We must in such situation change input value to **value-(value below 0)**.

```
if (newbalance < 0) {
 alert('You Can Not Cash out more than your Balance!');
 //my code
 $('#accountbalance').text("0.00"); //set 0 in balance UI
 $(this).val(parseFloat(parseFloat($(this).val())+newbalance).toFixed(2)); //set currently changing input val to val +newbalance so if balance is minus it will left only possible amount
 //end of my code
 return false;
}
```

Other changes are connected with fixing convertion to float and float operations. Fo example from:

```
newbalance = (parseFloat(accountbalance).toFixed(2) 
            - parseFloat(removebalance).toFixed(2));
```

to

```
newbalance = (parseFloat(accountbalance) - parseFloat(removebalance));
```

Change is important because **toFixed**(http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp) converts number to string so You where doing operation on strings not on numbers. Method **toFixed** should be used only to presentation.

Comment: But when you subtract js does the thinking for you when it comes to types :-) not that its good practice but its true anyway

Comment: @LucasKot-Zaniewski yee but in this situation type convertion will change result.

Comment: Can you please give an example that would be relevant here?

Comment: @LucasKot-Zaniewski ok, check any floats operation, like for example paste in console: (parseFloat(12.955).toFixed(2) 
            - parseFloat(11.950).toFixed(2)); and (parseFloat(12.955) 
            - parseFloat(11.950)); . Second result is correct.

Comment: @LucasKot-Zaniewski problem is not with substract but with that we substract changed values by toFixed which roundes orginal values.

Comment: I understand but OP should not be allowing such values into the form if we are dealing with currency.

Comment: Yes, but I recommend to do operations on numbers not on strings. It is more clear in code.

Comment: Zgadzam sie w 100%

Comment: Zrelaksowany typing to obosieczny miecz!

Comment: Great, exactly what I was going for. It's amazing that two lines of code was able to achieve the missing element. Thanks for the help! And good info on the toFixed(2) first time I used it and didn't realize it converted numbers to strings.

Answer (score 0):

I have done what I think you want out of this script.
Have a look.

```js
var qty = $('input[type=text]');
var accountbalance = parseInt($('#accountbalance').text());
var removebalance;
var newbalance;
var inputCounter = 0; // zero-based

$('input').on('focusout', function() {
    //set removebalance to zero each time
    removebalance = 0;

    //check number iput and die if letters or negative number
    if (!$.isNumeric($(this).val()) || $(this).val() < 0) {
        $(this).val(0);
        return false;
    }

    //get total from all input fields
    $(qty).each(function() {
        removebalance += parseFloat($(this).val());
    });

    //set current balance
    newbalance = (parseFloat(accountbalance).toFixed(2) - parseFloat(removebalance).toFixed(2));
    $('#accountbalance').text(newbalance.toFixed(2));

    //Needs to set input to zero and not update #accountbalance
    //if entering more than #account balance
    if (newbalance < 0) {
        //alert('You Can Not Cash out more than your Balance!');
        return false;
    }

    // Set values to fixed on focusout
    thisValtoFixed = parseFloat($(this).val()).toFixed(2);
    $(this).val(thisValtoFixed);
});

//Cant submit if input is more than balance
$('#submit').click(function() {
    if (newbalance < 0) {
        //alert('You Can Not Cash out more than your Balance!');

        // Correcting last input

        $(qty).each(function() {
            var tempAmount = parseFloat($(this).val());
            if (tempAmount > 0) {
                $(this).val(tempAmount.toFixed(2));
                inputCounter++;
            }
        });

        // set corrected value
        var lastInputAmount = parseFloat($(qty).eq(inputCounter - 1).val());
        var correctedInputValue = lastInputAmount + newbalance;

        $(qty).eq(inputCounter - 1).val(correctedInputValue.toFixed(2));
        alert('You Can Not Cash out more than your Balance!\n\nWe corrected your last amount to ' + correctedInputValue.toFixed(2));
  
        // Show a zero balance
        $('#accountbalance').text(0.00);
        newbalance = 0;
  
        
        // Change the submit button for "Submit like this?"
        $("#submit").text("Submit like this?");
        return false;
    }else{
     // Ok to submit!!
        alert("Submitted.");
    }
});
```

```css
input {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <input type="text" name="value[]" value="0.00">
    <input type="text" name="value[]" value="0.00">
    <input type="text" name="value[]" value="0.00">
    <input type="text" name="value[]" value="0.00">
    <input type="text" name="value[]" value="0.00">
</form>

<div id="accountbalance">500.00</div>
<button id="submit">Submit</button>
```